# Expect to send the Ctrl+A to the browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, expect, screencast

I want to start google-chrome and then send the Ctrl+A to the chrome process, to begin recording with ScreenCastify. I have set the shortcut key for the ScreenCastify to Ctrl+A.
Following is the code snippet I have used:

```
!#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn google-chrome --new-window <url>
send "\x01";
interact
```

The Ctrl+A is not triggering the recording on the browser.

Comment: Expect cannot work with GUI programs like chrome. You might have better success with [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)

Comment: I used xdotool. Thanks a lot. its really easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expect cannot work with GUI programs like Chrome. So, I used `xdotool`.